# Why transliterate house as beth rather than beit or beis/bais?

Tags: transliteration

In various places we see the word house transliterated as beth rather than the ashkenaz or sefardic: beit or bais.  What is the logic of the beth transliteration?

Comment: FYI, my friend was in charge of Beth Hatevilla ("The Mikvah House") in Rochester. She stopped counting how many letters were addressed to "Beth", and how many calls she got asking for Beth.